# How to define a grad cam function for TF2.0+ keras CNN for image classification?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gradient

I'm trying to run CNN classifier on TF2.3. But I have a problem with The grad cam (saliency). I got the following error:

`tf.gradients` is not supported when eager execution is enabled. Use `tf.GradientTape` instead.

I saw there is some proposed solution, but I'm trying to use grad cam as a function.

This is my function :

```
def grad_cam(input_model, image, cls, layer_name, H=320, W=320):
    """GradCAM method for visualizing input saliency."""    
    y_c = input_model.output[0, cls]
    conv_output = input_model.get_layer(layer_name).output
    
    grads = gtape.gradient(y_c, conv_output)[0]

    gradient_function = K.function([input_model.input], [conv_output, grads])

    output, grads_val = gradient_function([image])
    output, grads_val = output[0, :], grads_val[0, :, :, :]

    weights = np.mean(grads_val, axis=(0, 1))
    cam = np.dot(output, weights)

    # Process CAM
    cam = cv2.resize(cam, (W, H), cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    cam = np.maximum(cam, 0)
    cam = cam / cam.max()
    return cam


def compute_gradcam(model, img, image_dir, df, labels, selected_labels,
                    layer_name='bn'):    
    preprocessed_input = load_image(img, image_dir, df)
    predictions = model.predict(preprocessed_input)

    print("Loading original image")
    plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
    plt.subplot(151)
    plt.title("Original")
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(load_image(img, image_dir, df, preprocess=False), cmap='gray')

    j = 1
    for i in range(len(labels)):
        if labels[i] in selected_labels:
            print(f"Generating gradcam for class {labels[i]}")
            gradcam = grad_cam(model, preprocessed_input, i, layer_name)
            plt.subplot(151 + j)
            plt.title(f"{labels[i]}: p={predictions[0][i]:.3f}")
            plt.axis('off')
            plt.imshow(load_image(img, image_dir, df, preprocess=False),
                       cmap='gray')
            plt.imshow(gradcam, cmap='jet', alpha=min(0.5, predictions[0][i]))
            j += 1
```

This code is from an online course.
I appreciate the help.

Comment: After importing `tf`, you can use this `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()`.

Comment: no you can't, if you disable eager_excution it dose not work because I'am using gradient (first function).

Comment: Like I said, after trying to disable eager execution:`ValueError: Calling `Model.predict` in graph mode is not supported when the `Model` instance was constructed with eager mode enabled. Please construct your `Model` instance in graph mode or call `Model.predict` with eager mode enabled.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tf.gradients is not supported when eager execution is enabled. Use tf.GradientTape instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66221788/tf-gradients-is-not-supported-when-eager-execution-is-enabled-use-tf-gradientta)

Comment: I saw, this answer, but the there some differences, he is using a vgg16, me densent121, also I want to get a method not running it on the flight. I really appreciate your help.