# Gradient in TF1 to GradientTape in TF2

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am implementing the example in the book "deep learning book with python" chapter 05.

I know I could disable eager by disable_eager_execution() but that's my second choice.

here is sample code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def deprocess_image(x):
    x -= x.mean()
    
    x /= (x.std()+ 1e-5)
    x *= 0.1
    x += 0.5
    x = np.clip(x, 0, 1)
    x *= 255
    x = np.clip(x, 0, 255).astype('uint8')

    return x



def generate_pattern(layer_name, filter_index, size = 150):
    layer_output = model.get_layer(layer_name).output
    loss = K.mean(layer_output[:, :, :, filter_index])
    grads = K.gradients(loss, model.input)[0]                       <------- here
    grads /= (K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(grads))) + 1e-5)
    iterate = K.function([model.input], [loss, grads])
    input_img_data = np.random.random((1, size, size, 3)) * 20 + 128.
    step = 1.
    for i in range(40):
        loss_value, grads_value = iterate([input_img_data])
        input_img_data += grads_value * step
    img = input_img_data[0]
    return deprocess_image(img)

def generate_pattern_grid(layer_name):
    size = 64
    margin = 5

    results = np.zeros((8 * size + 7 * margin, 8 * size + 7 * margin, 3))
    for i in range(8):
        for j in range(8):
            filter_img = generate_pattern(layer_name, i + (j * 8), size = size)

            horizontal_start = i * size + i * margin
            horizontal_end = horizontal_start + size
            vertical_start = j * size + j * margin
            vertical_end = vertical_start + size

            results[horizontal_start : horizontal_end, 
                   vertical_start : vertical_end, :] = filter_img

    plt.figure(figsize = (20, 20))
    plt.imshow(results.astype('uint8'))


model = VGG16(weights = "imagenet",
             include_top=False)

layer_name = "block3_conv1"

generate_pattern_grid(layer_name)
```

this will give me

```
RuntimeError: tf.gradients is not supported when eager execution is enabled. Use tf.GradientTape instead.
```

and I've read the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager#computing_gradients) and try this:

```
def generate_pattern(layer_name, filter_index, size = 150):
    layer_output = model.get_layer(layer_name).output
    loss = K.mean(layer_output[:, :, :, filter_index])
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss = K.mean(layer_output[:, :, :, filter_index])
    grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.input)
    grads /= (K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(grads))) + 1e-5)
    iterate = K.function([model.input], [loss, grads])
    input_img_data = np.random.random((1, size, size, 3)) * 20 + 128.
    step = 1.
    for i in range(40):
        loss_value, grads_value = iterate([input_img_data])
        input_img_data += grads_value * step
    img = input_img_data[0]
    return deprocess_image(img)
```

but got

```
AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute '_id'
```

Is there any solution to this?

I guess if there is any way to transform kerasTensor to tfTensor then I might solve this but I can't found it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tf.gradients is not supported when eager execution is enabled. Use tf.GradientTape instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66221788/tf-gradients-is-not-supported-when-eager-execution-is-enabled-use-tf-gradientta)

Comment: @OmG I've read that but I have no idea about how to implement it in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tf.gradients` is deprecated in Tensorflow v2. As error message says use `tf.GradientTape` in place of Tf.gradient. For more information visit [tf.GradientTape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape)

For Tensorflow v1, disable the eager-execution.

Take a look at [tf.GradientTape for Keras users](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/tf-gradienttape-explained-for-keras-users-cc3f06276f22).